# chrome.management functionality in apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm new to making chrome apps and extensions, working on my first app. I need access to alist of the installed apps on chrome with their relevant details and icon, so I used `chrome.management`. However, when I try to use it in my app, I get the error

```
'management' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps,
but this is a packaged app.
```

Looking at the api page, `chrome.management` is indeed not listed under the "Apps" tab, but the "Extensions" one.

Is there any other way I can have access to the information in an app? Chrome app launcher did it... not sure if there were any super secret special permissions involved.

Comment: You will need both an app and extension. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Comment: @DanielHerr Does it work with apps though? I see no documentation for use with apps, only extensions.

Comment: Messaging works with apps, chrome.runtime is listed at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index